# I want to create a pattern of nxn in java with the help of loops

Tags: java, loops

I want to create a pattern like this, why is this code wrong?

```
x x x x

x x x
  
x x

x
```

for any value of n( its a nxn pattern )

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = n; i <= n; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: `i <= n` -> `i >= 0`

Comment: got it, Thank you

Comment: also, why did it not run when i<=n

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below "i" is decremented, so it will never reach to i<=n as your `i` will be always less than `n`, that will hold true forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You condition is wrong it should be `i >= 0`. In your case where `i <= n`, "i" is decremented and will never reach "stop condition".

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: also, why did it not run when i<=n

Comment: As mentioned in the answer above  "i" is decremented, so it will never reach to `i<=n` as your `i` will be always less than `n`

Comment: I didn't downvote, and it understandable sometimes we don't realize a small change in the program.